# opening a gzipped fil, characters following three pipes ("|||") are not visible

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

My input file is a gzipped file containing genomic information. I'm trying to parse the content on a line-by-line basis and have run into a strange problem.

Any given line looks something like this:

> AC=26;AF=0.00519169;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=17308;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0.0072;AFR_AF=0.0015;EUR_AF=0.0109;SAS_AF=0.0082;AA=A|||;VT=SNP

However, when I print out what is being read in...

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(myfile.gz, 'rt') as f:
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

The line looks like this:

> AC=26;AF=0.00519169;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=17308;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0.0072;AFR_AF=0.0015;EUR_AF=0.0109;SAS_AF=0.0082;AA=A|||

Whatever information comes after the "|||" has been truncated.

Moreover, I can't even search the lines for strings that follow the "|||"  (e.g. `"VT=SNP" in line` always returns False)  I also can't `line.strip("|||")`

Any advice on what is causing this or what I need to look at?

Thank you for any help

EDIT: ok, it looks like there was something wrong with the gzip file. I uncompressed it and the script ran fine.  Then I recompressed it and the script again ran fine (using gzip.open).  Is there any straightforward way to compare the two compressed files (ie, the one that doesn't get read properly vs the one that works) so that I might get a hint at the root cause?

Comment: Did you close the file properly when generating it?

Comment: Yes, closing is important--compressors keep a buffer in memory that they might not flush when you want if you don't tell them to by closing or writing. If it's not that, run `gunzip` on the file to check whether the problem is that some data didn't make it into the compressed file or it's something happening on decompression.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows in Python 3.4.4. "VT=SNP" prints fine for me. But I had to generate a gz file from your one line example. Also in code  myfile.gz should be in quotes and for loop needs to be indented.

Comment: I uncompressed the file and all works as expected, so I suspect this is related to gzip or to how the file was originally compressed.  Will now recompress to see if related to original file compression or to gzip itself...

Comment: This may be due to the printing, not the gzip decompression. There may be an unprintable character after the three bars. Can you provide a link to the gzip file?

Comment: I edited my post above to reflect the fact that my script works as expected if I first uncompress and then recompress the .gz file...not an ideal solution but at least it works. The files that I'm working with are the .vcf.gz files from this archive (ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/)